# How to cache images and data to avoid repeated loading?

Tags: c#, xaml, caching, uwp

When I ran my UWP app, I figured that it loads the same images every time I navigate to another page and go back to it. How do I avoid it?

Plus, how to use the `NavigationCacheMode` correctly? I set it to `Enabled` in XAML, but seems not working. Is there something missing?

Comment: Setting `NavigationCacheMode` should avoid reloading the page after coming back. You need to show more info.

Comment: You could try setting it to `Required` but I don't think it'd help.

Comment: You may always create static class aka Resources and load everything you wish to reuse like BitmapImages and just bind them. {x:Bind xmlnsName:YourStaticClass.YourBitmapImage}

Comment: Please post some code where you are loading Image.